# Always On Windows Server Edition

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, windows

For setting up Always On Availability Groups in SQL Server I know you need to have at least Enterprise Edition for SQL Server 2012, 2014, or 2016.

Do you also need the Datacenter or Enterprise Edition of Windows Server 2012 or 2016 for Always on, or can you set this up properly on Windows Server Standard 2012 or 2016?

Comment: Just to add starting from SQL Server 2016 we have [Basic Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) in standard edition which is *trimmed* version of availability groups.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you also need the Datacenter or Enterprise Edition of Windows
>   Server 2012 or 2016 for Always on, or can you set this up properly on
>   Windows Server Standard 2012 or 2016?

Windows Server Standard Edition is fine.

Starting with Windows Server 2012 every feature of Windows Server is available in Standard Edition.  In particular Standard Edition supports Windows Server Failover Clustering which is needed for some Always On capabilities.

Comment: We plan to use Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) so we don't need to setup shared storage instead of Failover Cluster Instances (FCI), Given this scenario I believe Windows Server Standard would serve our needs.

If you say that every feature of Windows Server is available in Standard Edition, what makes Windows Server Datacenter any different than Windows Server Standard and when would you need Windows Server Datacenter Edition instead of Windows Server Standard edition?

Comment: When you license a server with Windows Server Datacenter Edition you can run Windows in any number of VMs on that server.